# In XSLT 2.0 how can I insert into endresult.xml's <Set> element the set name from the Sets.xml file if it exists in <CardName>?

Tags: xml, xslt

In XSLT 2.0 how can I insert into endresult.xml's  element the set name from the Sets.xml file if it exists in`<CardName>`, otherwise leave blank>?

**endresult.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MagicCards>
    <MagicCard>
        <Cardname>MTG Chord of Calling - Foil Magic 2015 Near Mint, English </Cardname>
        <Price>15.99</Price>
        <ShippingCost>2.49</ShippingCost>
        <SoldTimestamp>2015-07-01T12:16:02.000Z</SoldTimestamp>
        <Quantity />
        <Condition>NEAR MINT</Condition>
        <IsFoil>FOIL</IsFoil>
        <Set>Magic 2015 Core Set</Set>
    </MagicCard>
    <MagicCard>
        <Cardname>Mtg Chord Of Calling X4 Non- Foil Green Rare M15</Cardname>
        <Price>20.29</Price>
        <ShippingCost>2.25</ShippingCost>
        <SoldTimestamp>2015-06-30T01:52:13.000Z</SoldTimestamp>
        <Quantity>4</Quantity>
        <Condition />
        <IsFoil>FOIL</IsFoil>
        <Set />
    </MagicCard>
</MagicCards>
```

**Sets.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sets>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>M14</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Magic 2014 Core Set</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>THS</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Theros</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>BNG</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Born of the Gods</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>JOU</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Journey into Nyx</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>M15</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Magic 2015 Core Set</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>KTK</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Khans of Tarkir</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>FRF</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Fate Reforged</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>DTK</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Dragons of Tarkir</SetName>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <SetShortName>ORI</SetShortName>
        <SetName>Magic Origins</SetName>
    </Set>
</Sets>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MagicCards>
    <MagicCard>
        <Cardname>MTG Chord of Calling - Foil Magic 2015 Near Mint, English </Cardname>
        <Price>15.99</Price>
        <ShippingCost>2.49</ShippingCost>
        <SoldTimestamp>2015-07-01T12:16:02.000Z</SoldTimestamp>
        <Quantity />
        <Condition>NEAR MINT</Condition>
        <IsFoil>FOIL</IsFoil>
        <Set />
    </MagicCard>
    <MagicCard>
        <Cardname>Mtg Chord Of Calling X4 Non- Foil Green Rare M15</Cardname>
        <Price>20.29</Price>
        <ShippingCost>2.25</ShippingCost>
        <SoldTimestamp>2015-06-30T01:52:13.000Z</SoldTimestamp>
        <Quantity>4</Quantity>
        <Condition />
        <IsFoil>FOIL</IsFoil>
        **<Set>M15</Set>**
    </MagicCard>
</MagicCards>
```

Comment: Is this a correct restatement of your question: If any token (for some specification of "token") in `<Cardname>` matches the text value of a `<SetShortName>` tag in `Sets.xml`, then put that matched value into the `<Set>` tag; Otherwise (no token matches any such value), set the value of the `<Set>` tag to empty.  If this is correct, you still need to clarify what a "token" is, i.e. how the `Cardname` is to be parsed to extract tokens to lookup in `Sets.xml`.

Comment: What I'm saying is look at the CardName in endresults.xml and if within that CardName there exists a substring that matches a SetShortName or SetName in sets.xml then put the match found into the Set element of the desired output. For example, the CardName is "Mtg Chord Of Calling X4 Non- Foil Green Rare M15" and M15 is a SetShortName in sets.xml so take that value and put it into the Set element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have provided you can try out this. I have started from the point where the xslt parser is already on the "MagicCard" node of your endresult.xml.

```
  <xsl:variable name="setData" select="(document('Source2.xml')//Set)"/>      
  <xsl:for-each select="MagicCard">
    <MagicCard>
      <xsl:variable name="curCardname" select="Cardname"/>
      <xsl:variable name="curMagicCard" select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='Set']"/>
      <Set>
        <xsl:for-each select="$setData">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($curCardname,SetShortName)">
              <xsl:value-of select="SetShortName"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($curCardname,SetName)">
              <xsl:value-of select="SetName"/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Set>
    </MagicCard>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

The variable setData in the second for-each loop contains the collection of Set nodes from your Sets.xml.

I have saved your Sets.xml data in another file and used below code to set the variable

```
  <xsl:variable name="setData" select="(document('Source2.xml')//Set)"/>
```